# How to get JavaMail trace in EBCDIC?

Tags: debugging, jakarta-mail

I've turned on tracing my JavaMail-based application, and I can see the trace, but it looks like garbage because it is in unicode and my machine only knows EBCDIC. Is there anyway I can get the trace to print out with the default encoding for my machine (EBCDIC)? Here is how I activate the trace:

```
session.setDebug(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the trace goes to System.out.  If System.out isn't converting to EBCDIC, you can create your own PrintStream that does so and use the session.setDebugOut(ps) method to set it.

Comment: I knew there had to be a way to do this! Many Thanks!